# How to go back to initial Screen for drawer when opening deeplink with backBehaviour as history?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using a Drawer Navigator as my base with history and have a Home screen and a Notifications screen.

Now for a deeplink myapp://notifications i want to have a history like Home->Notifications so that on pressing physical back btn the user is taken to Home instead of closing the app.

However it seems this does not work with backBehaviour set as history as now Home is never added when opening deeplink.

Is there any way to update the history so that it always has Home as initial screen?

(I have set Home as Initial screen in my linking config but that does not help)

Comment: Looking for same solution

Answer (score 0):

> The `reset` action allows resetting the navigation state to the given state.

Try to run this `dispatch` if your app opened using the deep link

(Untested) example:

```js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch((state) => {
  // Add the home route to the start of the stack
  const routes = [{ name: 'Home' }, ...state.routes];

  return CommonActions.reset({
    ...state,
    routes,
    index: routes.length - 1,
  });
});
```

Read more about [reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset) action